# Leaflet: Add a link to the markers

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

Pretty simple question: How can I make the map markers in Leaflet clickable and route the user to an other page? Every marker has its own page.

I've tried the following without success; somehow all the markers point to the same page, which is the last assigned URI.

```
var markers = [
    { coords: [51.505, -0.09], uri: '/some-page' },
    ...
];

for(x in markers)
{
    L.marker(markers[x].coords).on('click', function() {
        window.location = markers[x].uri;
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

This issue is really driving me nuts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I finally came to a solution; when a marker is added to the map it gets assigned an ID called "_leaflet_id". This can be fetched through the target object, and also set to a custom value *after* it has been added to the map.

So the final solution is simply:

```
var x = markers.length;

while(x--)
{
    L.marker(markers[x].coords).on('click', function(e) {
        window.location = markers[e.target._leaflet_id].uri;
    }).addTo(map)._leaflet_id = x;
}
```

(I replaced the for-in loop with a reversed while loop)

Comment: You shouldn't use a `for..in` loop to iterate arrays.  Also, you're leaking `x` into the global scope; use `var`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a popup which can display HTML

marker.bindPopup(htmlString);

Comment: True, but then the user has to click two times instead of one.

Comment: Map markers usually don't open a new URL, so a popup would be the preferred way. You could trigger it automatically, and it'll just display, or on hover. The user should know what is going to happen when they interact with the objects you give them, otherwise you get frustrated users.

Answer (score 3):

i found a similar code which may help you. here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/farhatabbas/qeJ78/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        init_map();
        add_marker();
    });
    var map;

    function init_map() {
        map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/22677/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2012 CloudMade',
            key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707'
        }).addTo(map);
    }

    function add_marker() {
        var points = [
            ["P1", 43.059908, -89.442229, "http://www.url_address_01.com/"],
            ["P2", 43.058618, -89.442032, "http://www.url_address_02.com/"],
            ["P3", 43.058618, -86.441726, "http://www.url_address_03.com/"]
        ];
        var marker = [];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            marker[i] = new L.Marker([points[i][1], points[i][2]], {
                win_url: points[i][3]
            });
            marker[i].addTo(map);
            marker[i].on('click', onClick);
        };
    }

    function onClick(e) {
        console.log(this.options.win_url);
        window.open(this.options.win_url);
    }
```